# Функция не реагирует на кнопку Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

после запуска это часть кода не работает "@router.message(Command("Заполнить анкету"))", ни какой ошибки не выдает.

```
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram import Router, types
import keyboards as kb


router = Router()

@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message:Message):
   await message.answer(f"Привет", reply_markup=kb.main)

class Reg(StatesGroup):
    first_name = State()
    last_name = State()
    middle_name= State()

@router.message(Command("Заполнить анкету"))
async def reg_one(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Reg.first_name)
    await message.answer("first_name:")

@router.message(Reg.first_name)
async def reg_two(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(first_name=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Reg.last_name)
    await message.answer("last_name:")
    

@router.message(Reg.last_name)
async def reg_three(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(last_name=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Reg.middle_name)
    await message.answer("middle_name:")

@router.message(Reg.middle_name)
async def reg_four(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(middle_name=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await message.answer(
        f"Спасибо.\n"
        f"Имя {data['first_name']}\n"
        f"Фамилия: {data['last_name']}\n"
        f"Отчество: {data['middle_name']}"
    )
    await state.clear()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой фильтр в хендлере - это текст, ане команда. Что бы бот реагировал на фразу "Заполни анкету", хендлер нужно переделать используя магический фильтр:

```
from aiogram import F

@router.message(F.text == "Заполнить анкету")
async def reg_one(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Reg.first_name)
    await message.answer("first_name:")
```

Тогда, при отправке текста "Заполнить анкету" будет срабатывать этот хендлер

Answer (score 1):

Не получается из за того что команды в Telegram могут быть только слитные, без пробелов.

Пример не правильной команды: /start menu

Пример команды правильной команды: /start_menu

Comment: вы были правы, но все равно приходится  добавить "/" без него никак, но на кнопке текст со слешем не очень, есть какой ни будь выход. Спасибо.